# Find Processor Type from compact .net 1.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

My application is targeted for Compact .Net 1.0 framework. The application has to check and download any updates available from a web-site. I am thinking of providing the updates as CAB files. Since the CAB files are processor type specific, I want to download the CAB file based on the Processor Type. What is the API for getting the Processor type (ARM/SH/MIPS/etc)?

Thanks,
Kishore A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing available directly from within the managed libraries. You'll need to use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/invoke) to call into the native `Coredll.dll` and use a method called [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms960847.aspx).

**pinvoke.net** is an excellent resource for using P/Invokes for both mobile and desktop development. The pertinent entry for you is:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.GetSystemInfo

Calling this method will return a [SYSTEM_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms942639.aspx) structure that contains information about the processor architecture.

If that route looks like too much work, you can always check out a commercial package called Smart Device Framework from OpenNETCF:
http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx

In the SDF, you'll be interested in `OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.DeviceManagement.SystemInformation` -- that will return the same basic information as the P/Invoke, but within a nice managed wrapper.